# How is endpoint throwing error not callable?

Tags: flask

I have implemented a basic `view.py` with below 
    from flask_restplus import Resource, reqparse

```
# the below order matters
from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('email', help = 'This field cannot be blank', required = True)
parser.add_argument('password', help = 'This field cannot be blank', required = True)

@auth.route('/registration')
class UserRegistration(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = parser.parse_args()
        new_user = models.Users(
            email = data['email'],
            password = data['password']
        )
        try:
            new_user.save_to_db()
            return {
                'message': 'User with email: {} was created.'.format( data['email'])
            }
        except:
            return {'message': 'Something went wrong'}, 500
```

but when  I access the registration endpoint using POST method i get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'UserRegistration' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is not callable...and your decorator is calling it.

Try adding a constructor (__init__) to your class. Or, if the decorator expects a function, convert it to a function.

Comment: yep, no where written in documentation.